# TrueCrypt - System partition or drive encryption without pre-boot authentication

Tags: operating-systems, truecrypt

I can't seem to find a way to encrypt my entire system partition or the entire drive and be able to skip the pre-boot authenticaion.

I need to be able to boot the machine into the normal encrypted system partition without a pre-boot authentication, so my sister can use the computer using her windows login. But I need the encryption if she ever tries to put the HDD on another computer as a removable drive...

I COULD use file containers, but we also want to encrypt files like "hosts" in the windows/system32/drivers/etc folder.

Does anyone know how to do this?

Thanks

PS: I use both Linux and Windows, so whichever answer there is, I can try.

Edit: I was thinking of saving a hash of my password for TrueCrypt boot loader to use, somewhere. I know it would be possible to find this hash and even reverse this hash given time, but I just need something to make it a little bit harder than just plugging my HDD on another computer and browse through my files...

Sorry, left a piece of important information out. My sister wants to see and use the programs I do so she can learn more about computer stuff. I think that's a good thing, so I wanna help her like that. Btw, I RARELY see her, because we study at different times, so always typing the password whenever she wants is not a really viable option.

Comment: "I need to be able to boot the machine into the normal encrypted system partition without a pre-boot authentication"  Once your system is encrypted, the only way to boot up is to authenticate the computer... How else could it decrypt your hard drive to load Windows?

Comment: Like I said in my edit, I was thinking if the TrueCrypt boot loader could save the hash or even the password itself somewhere to use at boot. I know it compromises security a lot, but it's just a simple way to make things harder for people to simply browse our files.

Comment: It doesn't compromise security "a lot," it compromises security *completely*. That's the problem. This type of authentication would make the encryption meaningless.

Comment: But for this case, I don't need the security like that. I just want to make it a little harder to be able to browse through my files and still be able to let my sister use the computer without her knowing the pre-boot authentication. If you know any other software like that, please point me to it. Thanks.

Comment: @SleepyMan this is why you use normal TrueCrypt containers in daily operation - you keep only the files you want encrypted.  There's no point in the performance hit of encrypting your whole drive for those few files you *actually* need to be hidden.

Comment: Well... like I said in the original question, I COULD use file containers, but I also want to encrypt files like "hosts" in the Windows/System32/drivers/etc folder... if I put that file in a encrypted file container, Windows won't find it anymore, or probably will just ignore it...

Comment: What are you putting in the Host file that is sensitive information? If you are worried about people *editing* the hosts file, just make sure no one but you has administrative privileges, only a administrator can edit the hosts file.

Comment: Just some sites that I block and redirect... Sorry, just personal sites that I can't really share here... And well... any person would be able to read and edit it if they plugged it in another computer as a Removable Drive if the drive or partition is not encrypted.

Comment: If you want to protect **System** resources from being read you will need to go with a dual boot solution, however I may have a trick up my sleeve... :)

Comment: Sorry, forgot to share one of the comments. I edited the post accordingly now. My sister wants to see all the programs I use, so dual booting would kill that. What is this trick you speak of?

Comment: @SleepyMan see my update.

Comment: @SleepyMan I'm not trying to give you a hard time here, but you're severely over-complicating the matter.  Create two passworded user accounts (one for you and one for your sister), and use a shared password for the boot menu.  Done.  All your data is encrypted, and you can create a restricted user account for your system (if that's what you need).

Comment: I know it seems to be over-complicating matters, but my sister is the kind of person who learns FAST, and she already knows how to use TrueCrypt. She is basically the only person who would know how to mount the encrypted disk on another computer knowing the password. So if we have a shared password she'll probably be able to alter the hosts file, which is something I UTTERLY do not want. So having that kind of setup is not possible for me. I know it seems over-complicating, but I just needed to make it a little harder for her and my friends, like hiding the hash of pwd in the MBR or something.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use Windows' [Encrypted File System](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Encrypting_File_System) you can Encrypt your sensitive document folders, however **[BE SURE TO BACKUP THE DECRYPTION CERTIFICATE](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows-vista/Back-up-Encrypting-File-System-EFS-certificate)** and store it on something outside of the computer (a USB key or other computer). There is a very good reason it is called the [Delayed Recycling Bin](http://www.dansdata.com/io021.htm), if you do not backup the certificate and your password is not changed using the normal change password methods (type in the old one, type in the new one twice) you will never be able to get to the files.

If you re-install windows (even if you use the same username and password) you will need the backup of the cert to get your files back, if you did not backup the cert before doing the re-install **THERE WILL BE NO WAY FOR YOU TO GET YOUR FILES BACK**).

I use the all caps-bold because I know you will think "I am careful, I will never need it" **DO IT ANYWAY**!!!

---

**Fix for Hosts File Issue**:
You can fix the Hosts file issue by using windows [Automatic Proxy settings](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc985352.aspx). Create a .pac file, encrypt it using EFS, then tell your web browser to use the auto-config settings from the file.

Here is a example of what to put in the file

```
function FindProxyForURL(url, host)
{
    if (0
    || dnsDomainIs(host, ".cn")
    || dnsDomainIs(host, ".doubleclick.com")
    || dnsDomainIs(host, ".doubleclick.net")
    || shExpMatch(host, "205.180.85.*")
    || shExpMatch(host, "66.40.16.*")
    || (dnsDomainIs(host, ".overstock.com") && shExpMatch(url, "*/linkshare/*"))
    || (dnsDomainIs(host, ".amazonaws.com") && shExpMatch(url, "*/udm_img/mid*"))
    || dnsDomainIs(host, ".gator.com")
    ) {
        return "PROXY 127.0.0.1:80";
    }
    else
    {
    return "DIRECT";
    }
}
```

The example is fairly self explanatory. it will redirect all of those listed items to localhost port 80.

---

**Original Answer**, talking about TrueCrypt and TPM. No longer my recommended solution

What you want is possible through a [TPM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trusted_Platform_Module), but [TrueCrypt does not support a TPM](http://www.truecrypt.org/faq#tpm). If the hash was not stored in hardware tied to a computer how would the drive know that it was in a different computer and happily auto-decrypt the data?

Also you need to ask your self, what are you protecting your self against. Pre-boot encryption only protects you from some very specific things:

- someone waling up to your computer and start using it from a powered down state
- taking the drive out of the computer and using it on another computer, or copying the drive then replacing your drive back.
- A OS running on a non encrypted portion seeing the shutdown OS in the encrypted portion.

What it ***does not do*** is protect you from someone using seeing/copying your files if the OS is already running (think virus/sister snooping around).

Remember:Once you are inside the encrypted envelope everything looks like normal unencrypted data to the OS and anyone using the OS.
Explain what you are trying to protect, and who you are trying to protect it from and we may be able to give you a better solution.

---

**EDIT**: when you say `I just want to make it a little harder to be able to browse through my files` who are you trying to make it harder for and in what way are they going to be performing the browsing?

Comment: Exactly, I don't plan on protecting while the system is running. ONLY when someone tries to simple plug it on another computer as a removable drive. That's it... Nothing more... I still want my sister to be able to use the computer as if it was NOT encrypted while it is using my encrypted system. Though I don't care if they plug it in another computer and boot my encrypted system, because then they would need my password to access my Document's folder.

Comment: If you `don't care if they plug it in another computer and boot my encrypted system` why are you encrypting it in the first place? If you want to do a setup like you want you will need to dual boot, one encrypted one not. There is no point in having a auto-decrpting system, it would just add IO overhead and no protection.

Comment: The "protection" from booting my encrypted system would come from the OS login system... if the person doesn't have a login, he wouldn't be able to use the computer NOR see any files within it. But if a person DOES have a valid login, let that person use the computer, but the other's Document's folders will be outside their scope. That's what I want. Edit: Encryption would just stop those who plug it in another computer as a Removable Drive (they do not have the knowledge to extract a key from the drive, just assume that please)

Comment: What you want in Windows Encrypted File System, it does exactly what you describe and it protects it from being put in another computer too as the still need your windows password to get to the file. BE SURE TO BACKUP THE CERTIFICATE OR YOU WILL LOOSE YOUR DATA!!!!

Comment: Answering your edit question: I want to protect from my friends who likes to gossip a lot... stupid stuff but kind of important for my social life.

The EFS seems to encrypt files and what not, but what about password resetting? I know I can reset user passwords for Windows XP and Windows 7 and gain total access if the entire partition is not encrypted. Does EFS protect system files against those attacks? Because something like Hiren's Boot CD and Trinity Rescue Kit are among the small tools that my friends use.

Comment: @SleepyMan As I said in my post, if you change the password in any other way than changing it from the logged in user and typing in the old password(That includes Hiren's Boot CD, Trinity Rescure Kit, and even a administrator clicking "Reset Password" for another user) you will no longer be able to read the certificate for your encrypted files, therefore the files will be forevermore unreadable (unless you made a backup of the cert and stored it somewhere safe like I told you to, That exported backup has it's own password so you do not need to worry about someone finding it and using it.)

Comment: I see, sorry I didn't understand at first. What about system files though? For now it just seems like a normal encrypted File Container. Can the EFS encrypt system files like the "hosts" file I mention in the question? Or would the system ignore it if encrypted?

Comment: I see, unfortunately, that doesn't block my sister's browsers if the file is only decrypted by me... Guess there really is no way to do the way I originally intended to, huh... Do you think there are other ways?

Comment: No, if it her browser can read it, she can read it. The only other option is put the filtering outside of the computer at the Router level or the DNS provider, which is out of the scope of this question.

Comment: Ok, gonna choose this answer as the closest alternative to my problem then. Thanks for pointing out all these alternatives, even though none were exactly how I expected.

Answer (score 2):

Truecrypt doesn't provide this capability, for the reasons stated above.

Please note that full disk encryption only protects your data from hard drive theft if the key, or access to the key protected by the passphrase, is stored outside of that system.

Any encryption where the key is on the same system as the data it is encrypting can (and usually will) be compromised.  Xbox, Wii, PS3, Xbox 360 have all tried this with their firmware and software keys and eventually failed to some degree.  It just buys them time.

It sounds like you want to allow your sister to use the system normally, but keep your use of the system private.  I would use Truecrypt to create an encrypted file container, and then use VMWare player to create a virtual hard drive within that file container and install/run your own "self-contained" and fully-encrypted operating system from that.  There will be a loss in performance but a gain in privacy; you have to decide what is more important.

Alternatively you could run Truecrypt full-disc encryption inside a VM.

Comment: Well the fully-encrypted OS in VM is not a bad idea if it wouldn't ask for a pre-boot authentication as well. Performance is not a problem for an i7 Extreme Edition with SSD, etc. Thanks.

Comment: It's **not possible** to eliminate the pre-boot auth.  However, your sister can use the actual machine and you can use the virtual machine.

Comment: Sorry, left a piece of important information out. My sister wants to see and use the programs I do so she can learn more about computer stuff. I think that's a good thing, so I wanna help her like that. Btw, I RARELY see her, because we study at different times, so always typing the password whenever she wants is not a really viable option.

Answer (score 1):

An encrypted filesystem without pre-boot authentication is just a slow unencrypted disk. The authentication is how the system knows what the encryption key *is*.

Comment: I know that's how it would work for a security expert. But my case is just to make it a little harder for people to browse through my HDD. I just don't want people to be able to just plug the HDD in another computer and browse my files. This level of "security" would scare off at least 99% of the people around me, and that's more than enough for me.

Comment: @SleepyMan anyone who knows enough to know to remove a drive and use it in another computer would have no trouble getting around your "Security".

Comment: Like I said, I know the people around me, they know almost nothing about these things... They are people who just "fix" computers by formatting and trying to salvage files plugging it in another computer... That's it... So for this case, just assume that this "security" is enough. Thanks.

Comment: This wouldn't make it harder for someone to browse through your HDD. When I want to look at the files on some USB stick I don't fire up my favourite hex-dumper and say "oh - that's an inode that points there, and that's a directory listing, and ... oh there's a textfile!". I plug it in and double click the textfile. By having encryption but no authentication, then sure, the bytes will look random on disk, but you've no protection from someone just plugging it in and taking a look around - which let's face it, is what someone would do if they wanted to see the files on your HDD.

Comment: Uh... sorry I think you are missing the point... If encryption is enabled on the entire disk, then if you plug it in another computer you will NOT be able to just double click the textfile because the filesystem would be recognized as RAW and NOT as the actual filesystem (like FAT32, EXT3 or NTFS)... So by using encryption, I would at least stop those who cannot find the key (even though it would be in the disk itself). If I'm wrong, and you CAN just plug it in my HDD in another computer and double click my textfile and read it like normal even when it is encrypted, please tell me so. Thanks..

Comment: You can. You just fire up TrueCrypt and see the files

Comment: Yes... but for that they would need to know 2 things: 1. that the HDD is encrypted by TrueCrypt and 2. the password I used to encrypt and decrypt the HDD... Like I said, assume they do NOT know how to obtain the password (which is my case here). My sister will probably know it's encrypted by TrueCrypt, but she does not have the knowledge to extract the password from anywhere, especially if it's hashed or anything. Let alone my friends.

Comment: They only need your password if you need to enter a password to see the files. Your original question was specifically about not needing to enter a password to get at the files - i.e. bypassing pre-boot authentication on the disk. If no password is needed, you only need to know that the disk is encrypted with TrueCrypt - and given that is one of only a few products that does disk-encryption, it's not going to be hard to guess. If you don't need to enter a password on boot, your sister, knowing that you've used TrueCrypt won't need to know your password to view the files either.

Comment: ... Let met rephrase it like I said in my first edit... bypassing the pre-boot authentication IN the boot loader like saving a hash of the password and using that to authenticate at the pre-boot time. Even if it was in plain text, it could be used automatically at boot time but NOT when someone tries to just mount it normally in TrueCrypt... The security compromise would be that they could just read the MBR and read the plain text password or the hash... but I am "100% SURE" they do not know how to do that. So, yes, they would NEED to enter a password to see the files if they try to mount it.

Comment: Unless they boot into it, in which case the MBR will automatically enter the password for them, and then they can just see your files. You seem to be missing the fundamental point which is that if you don't need to enter a password to see the files, then neither do other people.

Comment: I think you are missing my point... THAT IS EXACTLY WHAT I NEED!!! I don't want to make them type out the password when it is booting the system... I just want to kind of force them to boot into my system to read the files (they would NOT be able to see my files due to access restrictions on their accounts once in the system)... This is what I'm trying to achieve: Allow booting of the system without password (they still need an OS account and password to be able to use the OS) but require a password when mounting without booting using the TrueCrypt boot loader. Simple enough...

Comment: But my point is that if you can boot into the disk without typing a password, so can anyone else. It doesn't matter how good the encryption is, or how difficult the files are to read on disk. The default response from a non-technical user is not going to be firing up their favourite forensics program and being baffled by the randomness of the disk because of the encryption. It will be to turn it on - it'll boot without a password - and then they can see your files.

Comment: Let me see if I can explain in words you can understand. Booting into the system does NOT guarantee all the files will be readable by a random user. Booting into the system AND logging in as root might. The OS will protect my files once the system is booted through different permissions to different accounts. My sister's accounts is NOT a superuser account, nor does she know my root password. The only way she knows how to read and alter the files on the HDD is plugging it in another computer and accessing the files directly if it is not encrypted. Can you understand what I'm trying to achieve?

Answer (score 1):

A bit late to answer but here's my two cents :)

Maybe sleep mode would give you what you need, when your pc wakes up from sleep mode you do not have to give the pre-boot password. If the PC powers down or the drive is connected to another machine the password would need to be given again.

Answer (score 0):

If you only want decryption to happen on one specific machine the encryption has to be done by hardware on THAT machine, which does not exist on another machine. They then need to take more than just a hard drive to access the data. truecrypt is software based so a no go.

For the boot loader, The question is how will it know that it's in this machine not another one. The hard drive is the only permanent memory and if you put the password there you they will take with the hard drive and have it work automatically just like on your machine defeating the purpose. Hashed or not.

if you are thinking of setting the boot loader to read something specific from your machine and use it as a password. serialnumber, motherboard model no, mac address or a password stored on another hard drive etc. I wouldn't recomend it here is why.

first, given what you'r saying they will crack this easily. and it's not even worth the effort. also this doesn't solve the sister problem. she can figure it out pretty easily. and I don't know how to set the truecrypt loader to read the password from hardware specs which need to be unique to this machine like a serial number.

you can be creative with this but it will NOT be worth it.